# Am i infected with a malware or is it a graphic card issue?

Tags: windows-7, windows, virus, anti-virus, malware

This past month, i've been having many issues with malware, you can tell by looking at my profile, I'm so sick of it to the point where I'm really thinking to dump my windows, once and for all and go for linux. But it's easier said than done.

I've also had many troubles with my graphic card, it doesn't load linux, unless i use nomodeset, and many games don't work on windows. So I'm asking this question to help me determinate the issue.

Before I start, I'd like to say that this is the final question regarding this subject, if this topic won't fix my problem, I'll decide next week whether to dump windows or reinstall it.

I'm using windows 7, 64 bit, in the last 2 weeks, I installed and uninstalled the following antivirus in the hope of fixing the problem, MWB pro, MWB rootkit, windows anti rootkit, kaspersky anti rootkit, avg 2013 internet security, MSE, and bitdefender internet security 2014, which I'm using now, because avg license expired, and spybot and no I didn't install 2 real time anti virus at the same time.

All of those removed some malware (I don't like to say virus), but every time i start windows, 2 or 3 minutes later, i see a command prompt, that opens up and closes faster than you can blink, i strongly believe it's a spyware, but i can't prove it.

So i decided to fix it, yesterday, I downloaded bitdefender downloader, ran the downloader and went to sleep while it was downloading, next day my brother said that he had to turn off my laptop because i had bluescreen, which is strange.

There's a user here, i think he's Ramhound, he said `Do not try to scan a potentially infected system while running it. Shut it down, boot from something else, then scan from that other booted`

So I downloaded today bitdefender rescue cd, boot it up on my usb  and scan the pc, got 25 infections, with the same Trojan horse

[image]

I tried to delete them all (delete not fix) 23 got deleted, 2 got renamed.

And I tried to restart windows and see what i got (i captured it on my phone), when the windows starts, i see [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a5a9t4u00tdc9im/MOV_0182.mp4) and [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x1ff7hscwee4r3h/MOV_0181.mp4) (same thing, captured twice).

Why is this happening? By the way I checked the running processes, nothing suspicious, same thing with msconfig services (unless i'm missing something, since hackers sometimes use a name of a real program so the user wouldn't know about malware running on their system)

Comment: please note that is a Heuristics match.

Comment: refer to this answer: http://superuser.com/a/512901/179299 note: your best option is a format.

Comment: The graphical glitch isn't malware

Comment: @Ramhound i've seen malware do that. some sort of full screen app recording mouse clicks based on coords/pixelization colors.

Comment: Note that when a trojan is detected, it may not be running at all, but may be detected on your disk while at rest. if you can confirm that the trojan has never executed, there is no danger from it. Finally, if you are having repeated problems with malware, you are most likely downloading stuff you shouldn't (from a purely technical perspective, not a value judgement). the best anti-malware is a good dose of skepticism, and common sense, even if it means you sometimes can't get what you want.

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn `i've seen malware do that. some sort of full screen app recording mouse clicks based on coords/pixelization colors` could you tell me what malware do that kind of stuff? any name you can think of, or a way of identification

Comment: @FrankThomas how to know if a trojan has ever been executed? as for the second part, i spent a lot of time on pc and i had it for like a year, it is possible that i have downloaded some bad stuff or my friends gave me infected files, when you spend more than 3h a day on pc, it's hard to stay safe

Comment: @Fischer unfortunatly not, it was a gaming PC at a lanhouse. it got spread to other machines throught the network so i guess a worm (maybe a trojan pack too?). had to close the store for 1 whole day and re-image the pc's. didn't even run a scan since people used to access bank accounts on these pc's, wouldnt be safe to simply attempt to remove.

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn the reason i don't format is because i don't have a windows installation disk, windows was installed on the laptop by default, and I dualbooted the system installing a linux distro... if i format, I'll have to give it to the IT guys in some store, they will erase linux, coz they don't have linux disks and don't know how to back it up, and  they will erase all my programs, they'll back up only mp3 and things like that, but visual studio 2012 will be gone and many other programs, i'll have to download them again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and run ComboFix. You'll need to uninstall your antivirus software before it'll run, I'd recommend doing this all in Safe Mode. I've yet to encounter something ComboFix can't clean out, after getting passed reputable AV software.

Answer (score 1):

well Best Cure For malware and viruses is to not get them in the first place, beware of what you download and or install on to your computer, keep your firewall / antivirus up to date and run full system scans often and quick scans whenever you detect ANY malicious activity, such as a possible attack for instance, and If your firewall is telling you a website might be malicious close it and block it asap if there is anything suspicious about it at all, if it is offering you something that you probably should be having or making an offer too good to be true etc then just shut that web page down, and don't click on any links that are suspicious either, as for downloading programs , I scan every program that I download for viruses with my antivirus and firewall program before I open and if I find malware or any malicious content in the file I remove that malicious content from the  program (disinfect) and if that cannot be done simply delete the program, as it is better off to be without such a program that to get infected...and I have had I might say none virus Trojans and or worm malware infestations since I started doing that on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing after getting infected by malware is to do the following -> Make a low level format, flash the bios and install the operative system again. I advice you to use linux from now on though, current windows operative systems are really easy to infect and there are many privacy issues currently. 
Even if you are able to eradicate the malware without a low level format and flashing of bios... you cant be sure of a backdoor to be there still.
I would advice you to use herd protect scanner and metadefender aswell -herd protect is portable, and can be used as a second opinion software, it sends samples to more than 40 labs... if you are going to use windows again.-
Also make sure no other devices are in your network that could be infected. If you erase the infection and other infected devices are in your same network, you could get infected again.

Comment: advice to use a different os is not really answer